# Comparing adjacency matrices

Tags: r, graph-theory, networks

I have 25 weighted adjacency matrices which can be potentially translate into 25 networks. I want to see how ``similar'' are the resulting networks (in a graph theory sense).

Is there a way to do this in R?

Context: the 25 matrices are created by changing a tuning parameter. I essentially want to see the effect of the parameter on the resulting networks.

Thanks!

Comment: Correlation between the edge weights is probably a good idea. I'm not sure exactly what you mean by "a graph theory sense" though. I can only speculate because of lack of details, some entire graph level statistics might change (e.g. the density), but others (like whether it is small world or the number of different communities) I would expect would be less likely to change from network to network.

Comment: The most fundamental issue concerns what you really mean by "similar."  Would that mean similar *as matrices* or similar in the sense of *graph isomorphism*??  "In a graph theory sense" suggests the latter--but that is a *much* more difficult problem than a mere comparison of the matrices.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the objective of your analysis. For example, you can deduce a number of statistics from each matrix and compare the results. Otherwise, perhaps you can compute the Frobenius Norm between each pair of matrices. This will result in $25\times 24/2 = 300$ distances. Then, you can deduce which pairs are the closest. HTH.

Comment: Maybe you don't need to calculate all pairs of Frobenius norm. Since the network changes gradually by the tuning parameter, it should be ok to calculate the difference incrementally. If you plot tuning parameter vs Frobenius norm you should see where the network changes dramatically

Comment: similarly, it would be wise to plot the statistics that majeed simaan mentioned (node degree, number of edges, centrality, unconnected nodes, ...) against the tuning parameter.